# Generic IQueryable to CompareDate

Tags: c#, linq, generics, iqueryable

so I'm trying to create a function that takes in an IQueryable, and a DateTime Property in that IQueryable, and returns an IQueryable which is compared against another datetime.

Currently, I would have to do this for several different functions and this code may be subject to change so I would want this to be able to be applied generically to an IQueryable:

```
  FMGQueryableSet = FMGQueryableSet.Where(t => t.Created.Day >= StartDate.Value.Day)
                               .Where(t => t.Created.Month >= StartDate.Value.Month)
                               .Where(t => t.Created.Year >= StartDate.Value.Year);
```

Instead I want to be able to do this:

```
FMGQueryableSet = SetDateCompare(FMGQueryableSet, t=> t.Created, StartDate, false)
```

the Method Stub looks like this however I can't figure out how to tie the passed in property to the IQueryable

```
public IQueryable<T> SetDateCompare<T>(IQueryable<T> OriginalQuery, Expression<Func<DateTime>> QueryProperty, DateTime ComparisonDate, bool isGreaterThan = true) 
    where T : class
    {
        if(isGreaterThan)
        {
            OriginalQuery = OriginalQuery.Where(QueryProperty >= ComparisonDate.Day)
                            .Where(QueryProperty >= ComparisonDate.Month)
                            .Where(QueryProperty >= ComparisonDate.Year);
        }
        else
        {
            OriginalQuery = OriginalQuery.Where(QueryProperty <= ComparisonDate.Day)
                           .Where(QueryProperty <= ComparisonDate.Month)
                           .Where(QueryProperty <= ComparisonDate.Year);

        }
        return OriginalQuery;

    }
```

Comment: Hey check this out too! This will help you extend linq if you want to, http://trentacular.com/2010/08/linq-to-entities-wild-card-like-extension-method/

Comment: I believe there is a fundamental flaw in your logic.  Given Created as 2014-01-01 and StartDate as 2013-12-31.  The first `Where` is going to filter it out because 1 < 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really want the unusual comparison logic you showed, here is how you do it.  If you need different comparison logic, just changed the expressions ymdCompareLess and ymdCompareGreater.

First thing to do is to create a new expression that you can pass to a where clause.  You want to be able to pass in an expression indicating the property to compare and a date value to use in the comparison.

I created 2 expressions below for the less-than comparison and for the greater-than comparison.  Based on the value passed in for the isGreaterThan, we select the expression for the greater-than comparison or the less-than comparison.

I am using the Replacement Visitor pattern that I first saw here on StackOverflow to create a new expression by replacing all of the original parameters with other expressions.

Once we have selected the expression to use, we replace the parameters of that expression.  The first parameter, v1, will be replaced with our QueryProperty body.  Assuming you passed something like `v => v.CreatedDate`, the body of that expression will be `CreatedDate`.

The second parameter, v2, will be replace with an expression constant containing the date value you passed in.

The result will be that the created expression will look something like `v => v.CreatedDate.Day >= (new DateTime(2005, 2, 3)).Day` where `v` is the parameter from the expression you passed in.

Then we create a lambda expression with the created expression as the body and the parameter you passed in as the parameter.

And finally, we call the .Where method with our new lambda expression as the filter and return the result.

```
Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool>> ymdCompareLess = (v1, v2) => v1.Day <= v2.Day && v1.Month <= v2.Month && v1.Year <= v2.Year;
Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool>> ymdCompareGreater = (v1, v2) => v1.Day >= v2.Day && v1.Month >= v2.Month && v1.Year >= v2.Year;

public IQueryable<T> SetDateCompare<T>(IQueryable<T> OriginalQuery, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> QueryProperty, DateTime ComparisonDate, bool isGreaterThan = true)
        where T : class
{
    LambdaExpression comparisonExpression = isGreaterThan ? ymdCompareGreater : ymdCompareLess;

    var replaceVisitor = new ReplaceVisitor(
        comparisonExpression.Parameters.ToArray(),
        new[] { QueryProperty.Body, Expression.Constant(ComparisonDate) }
        );

    var whereBody = replaceVisitor.Visit(comparisonExpression.Body);

    var whereClause = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(whereBody, QueryProperty.Parameters);

    return OriginalQuery.Where(whereClause);
}

private class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    Expression[] _from;
    Expression[] _to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression[] from, Expression[] to)
    {
        this._from = from;
        this._to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        var idx = Array.IndexOf(_from, node);

        if (idx > -1)
        {
            return _to[idx];
        }
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The t=> t.Created part of your desired call its a lambda expression that represents a function that gets a DateTime from the type T, so your parameter for this should be a Func< T,DateTime>.

Having that in mind, you should try this:

```
public IQueryable<T> SetDateCompare<T>(IQueryable<T> OriginalQuery, Func<T,DateTime> getDateFunc, DateTime ComparisonDate, bool isGreaterThan = true)
where T : class
{
    if (isGreaterThan)
    {
        OriginalQuery = OriginalQuery.Where(t => getDateFunc(t).Day >= ComparisonDate.Day)
                        .Where(t => getDateFunc(t).Month >= ComparisonDate.Month)
                        .Where(t => getDateFunc(t).Year >= ComparisonDate.Year);
    }
    else
    {
        OriginalQuery = OriginalQuery.Where(t => getDateFunc(t).Day <= ComparisonDate.Day)
                        .Where(t => getDateFunc(t).Month  <= ComparisonDate.Month)
                        .Where(t => getDateFunc(t).Year  <= ComparisonDate.Year);

    }
    return OriginalQuery;

}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm testing it out now, I'm pretty sure this should work though!

Comment: What would the easiest way be to pass in the Second Variable, Lamba's apparent will not work

Comment: Lambda should do fine, whats not working? Did you specified the Type in your call? SetDateCompare<YourType>

Comment: sorry my intellisense was broken.  It's fine now

Comment: Hey So I tried to run this but I'm getting a compile time error 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'

Comment: On Execution I'm pretty sure It's because Entity Framework can only work with Expression<func<T,U>>, I would have to pull this into linq to objects to work this way

Comment: Oh, i see, Expression<func<T,U>> fixed the issue? If so i edit my answer

Comment: It should but I can;t figure out how to do it yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76386/discussion-between-rodrigo-lopez-and-johnny-5).